# mootools: make ajax callbacks to work with clicked element

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

Suppose I have a number of red colored links, and want to add a click event to them such that when it fires, it sends HREF attribute of link to server (as an AJAX request), and on success, the link color will be changed to green.
I want something like:

```
$$('a.red').addEvent(
    "click",
    function () {
        new Request.JSON({
            url: 'script.php', 
            onSuccess: function(){
                [the link wich is clicked].setStyle('color', 'green');
                return false;
            }
        }).get("url="+[url of the link]);
    }
);
```

Sorry if silly question. please edit title to some sensible one.

Comment: Is this related to what you are looking for?: __http://jsfiddle.net/v2LQ7/__

Comment: Exactly @Sergio :) Got it, The point was on "self" var... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `this` inside the event handler is not the same as `this` inside the Request Class. So What usually is done is to change the reference to `this` in a new variable, for example `var self = this`.

After that you can use `self.setStyle('color', 'green');`

By the way, a suggestion, the best would be to have also a class for the green color and switch them by the time of the click.

So here is a code suggestion would be:

```
$$('a.red').addEvent("click", function (event) {
    var self = this;
    event.stop();
    new Request.JSON({
        url: 'script.php',
        onSuccess: function () {
            self.removeClass('red').addClass('green');
            return false; // I added event.stop(), presume that is what you meant. Do this line can be removed
        }
    }).get("url=" + self.href);
});
```

and using in the CSS something like:

```
.green {
    color: green;
}
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/v2LQ7/1/)

Comment: Thank you. I applied a minor change in the last line, respect to your useful descriptions.

Comment: @MortezaE, great! Btw, if that link has a href you might want to have a `event.stop()` and pass `event` into the event hander. To prevent the page from following the link.